# Non-existent import files in pancake-swap-periphery

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, dapps, uniswap, defi

I'm looking for someone to give me a basic understanding and direction regarding pancakeswap forking. I cloned pancake-swap's periphery [repository](https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-swap-periphery) from github and in its contracts it imports
`"@uniswap/v2-core/contracts/interfaces/IPancakeFactory.sol"` for example. When I install uniswap a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jPEUt58_574&t=205s) on forking pancakeswap but it is very vague and doesn't seem to help me. Any help will be highly appreciated. Also why are there 2 router files instead of one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply created these interface files my self and the issue was resolved.